# Is it ok to move the start sector of my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, resize

I'm currently running two operating systems on my 1TB drive: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10.

I ran into a huge problem while updating 19.10 to 20.04 LTS: My Ubuntu partition ran out of space, and now for whatever reason I can't boot into the graphical UI of Ubuntu (after booting, it takes me to a black blank screen, the only thing I can do is access the Alt+F2 console, which works perfectly fine).

I only gave Ubuntu 100GB, so now I booted into Windows to try to resize the partition.

Problem: there is pretty much no space to allocate to the end of the partition, but I have ~50GB unallocated before the Ubuntu partition.
[image]
I'm afraid if I resize the partition by extending it leftwards, something might go wrong. Is it fine to extend it leftwards, or is that dangerous?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is intended to be upgraded to the next release, ie. 19.10 (and not 20.04).  Each release of Ubuntu can do this, though LTS release can upgrade to the next release OR the next LTS.  Ubuntu 19.04 was **not** a LTS so it's tested & supported path was to 19.10 (upgrades skipping releases are only tested with no additional software added so testing is all on you if you add packages as most of us do).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say 19.10, I am running 19.10. I edited the question